# How to find memory leaks using app dynamics

Tags: jvm, heap-memory, appdynamics

Could anyone explain me how to find memory leaks with the help of app dynamics.I tried to search but could not find any proper answer.

Comment: i don't know enough about appdynamics to give you a definite answer, but it looks more like high level monitoring. to find memory leaks you want a lower-level tool, a profiler, e.g. yourkit or jprofiler

Comment: When you are trying to use a commercial product, it is usually a good idea to contact them first, or use one of their forums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find detailed documentation on memory leak detection by AppDynamics from the following links (depending on whether you use Java or .NET):

https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO40/Automatic+Leak+Detection+for+Java

https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO40/Monitor+Memory+Usage+with+Object+Instance+Tracking+for+.NET